# How do I get my layers back?

Tags: interface, layers

My layers are gone and I'm in global view. How do I get them back? I've tried the numbers, shift + numbers, I'm in global view and nothing works. Please help![image]

Comment: Could you upload a bigger screenshot or a .blend?

Comment: @cegaton The OP says they are in global view (which was the issue in the question you linked).

Comment: yes, it worked!!! thank you! I had pressed the / button.